# sipml5 givin ns_error_unexpected in firefox 36.0.4 on two simultaneous incoming calls

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, sipml

I am getting ns_error_unexpected when there are two simultaneous "i_new_call"  event occurs.
Scenario 1 : When two intercom devices are pressed simultaneously, i receive two "i_new_call" event, after processing the events two icons are displayed on the screen to connect the call, when user click on connect there is no audio. And in console i can see "ns_error_unexpeted" from "addStream" method in SIPML5 js.

Scenario 2: when two intercom device are pressed one by one every thing works fine there is no "ns_error_unexpected" on cosole and both ends have audio

I am using Firefox 36.0.4 + SIMPL 1.5.23 + webrtc2sip + Asterisk 11.6 cert 9  on Red Hat 6

Answer (score 0):

Sipml5 looks like inactive project. Did you try [SipJS](http://sipjs.com) (or [JSSip](http://jssip.net)) and asterisk webrtc implementation (without webrtc2sip)? How to configure asterisk you can find under [Asterisk wiki page](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+WebRTC+Support)